# I am building an ALU in Verilog and my self-checking testbench keeps receiving this continuous blue error?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, modelsim, quartus

**I am tasked with building an ALU. However, I must not understand how the self-checking testbench with file.tv should run. I have run other simple testbenches just fine. I am sure there is a problem in the way that my testbench module is written,**

1. code compiles (using quartus)
2. made a text file with binary and turned it into a "test.tv" file
3. opened modelsim and added file
4. when I run it, is has an issue where it just keeps running blue errors..

Here is my code:

```
module ALU(input [31:0] a,b,
input [2:0] f,
output reg [31:0] y ,
output reg zero);

always @(*) begin
case(f)
        3'b000: y = a & b;  
        3'b001: y = a | b;  
        3'b010: y = a + b;    
        3'b011: y = 32'b0;    
        3'b100: y = a & ~b;
        3'b101: y = a | ~b;
        3'b110: y = a - b;
        3'b111: y = a < b;
     default: y = 32'b0;
endcase
    if(y==0)
        zero=1'b1;
    else
        zero=1'b0;
end
endmodule
```

//**********************

```
module ALUtest();
reg clk;
reg [31:0] a, b, yexpected;
wire [31:0] y;
reg [2:0] f;
reg zeroexpected;
wire zero;
reg [31:0] vectornum, errors;
reg [100:0] testvectors[10000:0];

ALU dut(a,b,f,y,zero);

always
begin
    clk = 1; #5; clk = 0; #5;
end

initial
begin
    $readmemb("test.tv", testvectors);
    vectornum = 0; errors = 0;
end

always@(posedge clk)
begin
#1; {a,b,f, yexpected,zeroexpected} = testvectors[vectornum]; 
end

always @(negedge clk)
begin
if (y !== yexpected) begin
$display("Error: inputs = %b", {a,b,f});
$display(" outputs = %b (%b expected)", y, yexpected);
errors = errors + 1;
end

vectornum = vectornum + 1;
if (testvectors[vectornum] === 4'bx) begin
    $display("%d tests completed with %d errors", vectornum, errors);
    $stop;
 end
end

endmodule
```

//*************************************

**CONTINUOUS ERROR THAT KEEPS RUNNING UNTIL I STOP IT:**

```
Error: inputs = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 outputs = 00000000000000000000000000000000(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx expected) 
Error: inputs = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 outputs = 00000000000000000000000000000000(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx expected) 
Error: inputs = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 outputs = 00000000000000000000000000000000(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx expected) 
Error: inputs = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 outputs = 00000000000000000000000000000000(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx expected)
```

**This is what my "test.tv" file looks like in binary**

```
00000000000000000000000000000000_00000000000000000000000000000000_010_00000000000000000000000000000000_1
00000000000000000000000000000000_11111111111111111111111111111111_010_11111111111111111111111111111111_0
00000000000000000000000000000000_01010101010101010101010101010101_010_01010101010101010101010101010101_0
```

**I know this might seem stupid and simple, but I am really trying to learn this and obviously do not understand something. Can someone please help? Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

`testvectors` is declared as:

```
reg [100:0] testvectors[10000:0];
```

`100:0` means `testvectors` is 101 bits wide, but you are comparing it to a 4-bit value (`4'bx` is the same as `4'bxxxx`).

Change:

```
    if (testvectors[vectornum] === 4'bx) begin
```

to:

```
    if (testvectors[vectornum] === {101{1'bx}}) begin
```

This stops for me using your 3-line `test.tv` file.

---

Note that the LHS (32*3+3+1) is 100 bits, but the RHS is 101 bits in the following expression:

```
{a,b,f, yexpected,zeroexpected} = testvectors[vectornum]
```

Also, you only specify 100 bits in the `test.tv` file.  Perhaps you should declare `testvectors` as 100 bits wide:

```
reg [99:0] testvectors[10000:0];
```